Should DNSSEC be done for glueless delegations?
Say I am a recursive resolver trying to resolve "a.example.com" with DNSSEC.
I get to the point where "example.com" is giving me a secure delegation for "a.example.com". There were no glue records in the answer so now I have to start a recursive sub-query for the nameserver's IP before I can continue with my main query.
My question is, should this sub-query do DNSSEC or not? My initial thought is no, because we have a secure delegation, even if the sub-query were to come back with a spoofed /A record and a fake IP for the nameserver, when we eventually try to query that IP it will not be able to produce a DNSKEY that matches the DS in the parent. Thus, the main query remains safe, but is there some risk I'm not thinking of here?

The DNSSEC status of a.example.com isn't relevant when you look up the nameserver IP address in a glueless delegation. Whenever you have a correctly glueless delegation, the nameserver in question must necessarily be outside of the domain in question, otherwise you'd have a Catch-22 that could only be resolved by the presence of glue.
The nameservers for a.example.com could still be in example.com, but the nameservers for example.com are in fact in another domain, one that has DNSSEC enabled:
$ dig +nocmd +nocomment +nostats +dnssec NS example.com
;example.com.           IN  NS
example.com.        17054   IN  NS  a.iana-servers.net.
example.com.        17054   IN  NS  b.iana-servers.net.
example.com.        17054   IN  RRSIG   NS 13 2 86400 20250107125830 20241217232048 2774 example.com. yuCJ26/N1ESW+FAn9KZDX849m1cv5QZEjW62+7b6BshyPPwvlUWCV5je VdNcjPFO6Vc33h4q2RaR4Lwn/UyyCQ==

$ dig +nocmd +nocomment +nostats +dnssec NS a.iana-servers.net
;a.iana-servers.net.        IN  NS
iana-servers.net.   3600    IN  SOA sns.dns.icann.org. noc.dns.icann.org. 2022092121 10800 3600 604800 3600
iana-servers.net.   3600    IN  RRSIG   SOA 8 2 3600 20250114131626 20241224175827 58389 iana-servers.net. 1vQ3hMVxJWlsnt1PuT3zA+3dc7QA3mBORJ2NE9N/U0Fe11MdKMiP/vjb lFPTnEe/4et+l1iHyghtEGG3Jz+kpEt/wM4fKqvV3Nqp0Pds5RMMIcGx 0U8f05loGPY2XY6HiQyuwW6wAAasrvluqrIu2YH8vzQLzVyX8czzu56Y vLM=
a.iana-servers.net. 3600    IN  NSEC    b.iana-servers.net. A AAAA RRSIG NSEC
a.iana-servers.net. 3600    IN  RRSIG   NSEC 8 3 3600 20250109035325 20241219012048 58389 iana-servers.net. b8UQVboBYjd8Oucpzwab3u6+Nz729xgaZE0Pcw6uLCoZalCdR/4KEoX9 ZUlw4yP8Jwa2jsdZXNTtfnzxXg8mCK6kD/tGn6U+iZavtfYcLPYqJUxi ecPiXXtlvsvwKIdH/HUD++btB2WLE42LaWTprrtI8n/1U9oMc1S2j7of 0RU=

If the iana-servers.net domain weren't securely delegated, then you shouldn't use DNSSEC to query for the nameserver addresses. So it is certainly true that you are not always required to use DNSSEC to query the nameserver addresses, and therefore implicitly it should be "secure" to do that even if the zone containing the nameserver names is securely delegated.
However, your question remains; should you use DNSSEC to query the nameservers in iana-servers.net for the query to the hypothetical nameservers (let's say they are ns-1.example.com and ns-2.example.com) of a.example.com?
I would put it another way, if there is a secure delegation to the zone containing the iana-servers.net nameserver names, why wouldn't you use DNSSEC? While you could use invalid or spoofed nameserver addresses for a securely delegated domain, you can't cache them safely (and caching is what makes DNS work at all). If you did cache them, there's always a risk that you might use those addresses for some other purpose (most likely as nameservers for non-securely delegated domains, but possibly for some other purpose like an SMTP or HTTP connection). Furthermore, the DNSSEC response can have some useful information, such as the other record types in an NSEC or NSEC3 record, that could potentially tell you that there's no point querying for a possible IPv6 address of the nameserver.
There's also a difference between "secure" and "reliable" - if you are getting spoofed addresses back for the example.com nameservers, you won't accept their unsigned or incorrectly signed responses, but you also might not get any other responses, so you are exposing yourself to a potential DNS denial-of-service.
On balance, I don't think that the benefits of omitting DNSSEC on a nameserver address query to a securely delegated zone outweigh the downsides. I suppose that if you don't get a response from any of the nameservers for the zone containing the nameserver names, there might be a possibility that a smaller non-DNSSEC-signed response might get through, or that the zone is incorrectly signed, and in that case you could make a query without DNSSEC (but you shouldn't cache it).
